# Automapper Map id from other table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have student class:

```
public class StudentsDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int? FkGraduates { get; set; }
    public int FkClass { get; set; }
    public int? FkClassNavigationFkTeacher { get; set; }
}
```

and class:

```
 public partial class Classes
{
        public Classes()
        {
            Students = new HashSet<Students>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int? FkTeacher { get; set; }

        public Teachers FkTeacherNavigation { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Students> Students { get; set; }
}
```

I want student class to have classes `FkTeacher`
In order to do so, I use automapper to map values, this is how I do it:

```
 CreateMap<Classes, StudentsDTO>().ForMember(dto => dto.FkClassNavigationFkTeacher,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.FkTeacher));
```

However, this does not work, I get `null` for `fkClassNavigationFkTeacher`

what's my mistake?

What I don't get is if I write `var classes = _classesService.GetAllClasses();` in my get method:

```
public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var classes = _classesService.GetAllClasses();
        var s = _service.GetAllStudents();
        return Ok(s);
    }
```

it returns `FkClassNavigationFkTeacher` how does that make sense?

Comment: the mapping seems correct. Are you sure the `FkTeacher` property has value before the mapping?

Comment: there are no null values in database, so there should be..

Comment: Ok, In database not is null. But in code? put a breakpoint before the mapping and evaluate the value you have retrieved from the database. Maybe the problem is there

Comment: Could you look at the updated question?